# Sitecore Rendering Parameter

Tags: sitecore, rendering

I have rendering items and I can open its property dialog pop-up by using below javascript.

`Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.postRequest("webedit:fieldeditor(command={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}, fields=field1|field2|field3, id={155DA3B8-41D9-4DA3-9D87-CBA72F67A0E2})");`

However, I had to add Parameter Template for one rendering item. So, I created parameter template (Custom Styles) like this screenshot, but below javascript is not working.

`Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.postRequest("webedit:fieldeditor(command={11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}, fields=CSS1|CSS2|CSS3|CSS4|CSS5, id={F7D900EF-9D68-4488-855D-B96FBF6D9F27})");`

[image]

I guess these fields are from parameter and I might have to use another command to call this pop-up, right? any idea, please?

This is what I found and there is `webedit:editrenderingproperties` command, but I don't know how I can use this command.

`Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.postRequest("webedit:editrenderingproperties(.......)");`

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2013/11/updated-field-editor-for-rendering-properties.aspx

Comment: If it's just rendering parameters then doesn't the "normal" way work? http://imgur.com/IzD5KfQ

Comment: @jammykam yes. it is correct. But, I'd like to know how "normal" way works. If you click the button, it shows pop-up so that you can update its field including defined parameter template fields. Mostly these pop-up is from PostBack and we can also use javascript as I mentioned, right??
And they provide "webedit:editrenderingproperties" command which seems like the editProperty button.

Comment: What are you trying to do? To edit fields on the item itself normally use edit frames, and the rendering parameters already is built in to sitecore.

Comment: I want to create "button" in page editor which will be the same function as "Edit Component Properties" by using 
`<a onclick="javascript:Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.postRequest("webedit:fieldeditor(....)")">Edit</a>`

Answer (score -2):

Try `webedit:ext:renderingfieldeditor` instead (*of course, if I understood your problem right*).

There is an article that describes exactly what you are looking for:

[Field Editor for Rendering Properties](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2013/10/field-editor-for-rendering-properties.aspx)

Comment: This is not working either. I can't find this command in command.config file. Even this command is working, there should be the argument for rendering item ID such as webedit:fieldEidtor